# Prevent iisnode from caching require'd static files

Tags: node.js, rest, caching, iis, iisnode

I have a RESTful API running on Node which operates on static files that live on the server's disk. If I run the service on Node (via the command line), I am able execute all CRUD operations on my collection of static files, and receive the expected HTTP responses to my HTTP requests.

However, when I take the same service and host it on IIS via iisnode, my GET requests seem to return cached versions of the files. That is, if I edit a file via the REST service, I can remote into the server and confirm that the update was made, but if I request the file via the RESTful API, I receive an old version.

I've tried the following, none of which have worked for me:

- bouncing IIS.
- disabling "cache" and "kernel cache" output caching on the web IIS web application.
- specifying no-cache in the Cache-Control header.
- removing the configuration for using iisnode's interceptor.

Any ideas on how to prevent iisnode (or iis) from caching my static files would be tremendously appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work-around to this issue. The solution was derived by reading through [this thread](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/58). The solution consisted of:

- **updating my iisnode tag watchedFiles attribute value** to reference the static (JSON) files that I wanted to trigger the Node process to restart. Changed from `<iisnode watchedFiles="*.js" />` to `<iisnode watchedFiles="*.js;relative/path/to/static files/*.json" />`
- **Recycle application's app pool.** This step is not documented in the thread, and I suspect is the reason others were having problems getting the solution to work.